# Calculating complex integral over contour

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

I'd like to calculate 
$\int_{\phi}^{} \frac{z^2}{z^3-1}dz$ where $$\phi(0)=i,\phi(1)=-1, \phi: [0,1] \rightarrow C$$ and $\phi((0,1)) \subset \left\{ z:|z|<1\right\}$
It seems pretty easy and straightforward, it definately requires applying Cauchy formula (after  the path is enclosed by second path let's say:
$\alpha(t)=-(1-t)$ for $t \in [0,1] $ and then $ \delta(t) = ti $)
but it gets rather messy and thus I believe I've missed somethink.Thank you for all your answers.

Comment: You can find an anti-derivative of the integrand. (Just be a little careful.)

Comment: Ahh that's right, a complex logarythm going from $C- [0,+\infty)$ will be fine

Comment: in general you can always apply partial fraction decomposition  and integrate, but here mrf advice is better.